# Unable to access Node app via reverse proxy using Nginx in Docker containers

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I have 2 separate Docker containers: Node app and Nginx running locally on a Windows machine. Both containers are up and running but I am unable to access my Node app via reverse proxy that I have set up in Nginx:

Node app container is ruuning using below  command:

```
docker run -p 2020:2020 --name nodeapp myimage:1.0
```

Node app is accessible at `localhost:2020` url

For the Nginx container I am using

```
docker run -p 7070:80 --name nginx mynginx:1.0
```

Nginx is accessible at `localhost:7070`

Below is my nginx configuration file:

**default.conf**

```
upstream nodeserver {
  server 127.0.0.1:2020;
}
server {  
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://nodeserver;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` from inside the docker will resolve to it's own localhost and not the Window's localhost.

Update the `server 127.0.0.1:2020;` to `server <Windows server IP>:2020;`. It should work.

Comment: Its working now thanks for pointing out the mistake is there any way where I can remove port as well because currently I am accessing at `localhost:7070` so can I eliminate 7070 by any means.

Comment: Great that it worked for you.

To eliminate the access of NGINX using `localhost:7070`, map it to port 80 so that `http://localhost` will resolve to port 80.

Comment: That I am mapping like this `docker run -p 7070:80 --name nginx mynginx:1.0` at the time of starting the nginx container.

Comment: `docker run -p <hostport>:<containerport>` is the syntax. So, it should be `docker run -p 80:80` to make it listen on `http://localhost`

Comment: What if I deploy these two containers over AWS ECS then would it requires remote server ip in place of windows ip is it correct?

Comment: If both the containers are in same docker network, then you can use the name of the container. In this case, it can be `nodeapp:2020`

Comment: Same docker network mean same cluster on ECS. If both have inside same cluster then we can connect them by there names

Comment: If it's the default settings, then it should work. There can also be additional networks in the cluster. You can check the networks in your cluster using `docker network ls` command.

Answer (score 1):

According to the previous answer yes, you should use Windows ip. Docker communicates each other with his containers using localhost ip, but outside container you should use Windows ip that should be:

```
192.168.99.100
```

Comment: What if I deploy these two containers over AWS ECS then would it requires remote server ip what I am understanding is.